# How to show the difference in value in grafana with prometheus between two times

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I have a json node exporter running and it exports my usage m3 of gas.
I want to see the daily usage of my gas usage.

Schematic:
sensor device exports json --> json  to prometheus data exporter --> prometheus --> grafan

Now I have the following graph:
[gas usage graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agXUe.png)
with using the query: `(gas_m3{bron="homewizard", instance="http://192.168.1.232/api/v1/data", job="json"})` and i use the query option now/d. ( i also can use: `gas_m3` )

What I want is that grafana shows the difference from midnight so that I can see the daily usage.
In formula terms I want the following: `gas_m3 - gas_m3@midnight`.
I have found that I can use epoch: `gas_m3 - gas@1686732307` but unfortunately this is not usable because this epoch is fixed.
Further with increase and sum no luck. Any suggestions, ideas?

Comment: If your panel starts with midnight, you can use `gas_m3 - gas_m3@start()`

Comment: Thank you so much, after 2 days searching and so simple. You make my day :-).